# recursively sync only specific files from specific subdirectories from a remote server

Tags: filesystems, rsync, remote, file-copy

The directory structure I have is as follows

```
./model1
./model1/correct_data/file1.txt
./model1/bad_data/file1.txt
./model2
./model1/correct_data/file1.txt
./model1/bad_data/file1.txt
```

I only need to sync `file1.txt` that is present in `correct_data` subdirectory.

rsync can be used to recursively sync only `file1.txt` from all subdirectories as

`rsync -zarvL  --prune-empty-dirs --include "*/"  --include="file1.txt"  --exclude="*"' <from> <to>`

However I'm not sure how to add the additional constrain the sync only to `correct_data` subdirectory

Answer (score 1):

I'd use this

```
(
  cd {from} &&
    rsync -zavLR */correct_data/file1.txt {to}/
)
```

The new ingredient is `-R` which applies the source path of each file to the destination root `{to}`. I've removed `-r` because it's implied by `-a`. The `-z` is only relevant if the target is actually a remote one. Are you really intending `-L`?

The subshell keeps the score of the `cd {from}` limited to the `rsync` command.

Comment: Thanks @roaima. Yes I need -L, because many of the files in the remote server directory are symlinked to other directories which must be copied locally. This command needs to be initiated from the remote server right? Unfortunately the local firewall at the moment prohibits this. Is there a way to initiate the transfer from the local machine?

Comment: @WanderingMind `-L` doesn't affect symlinks remotely unless you're using an older version of `rsync`. What it does is to dereference local symlinks into files (or directories) that should be copied as if they were the actual source. If you want to avoid breaking symlinks on the destination you should use `-K`.

Comment: I need them to be copied as source to destination (local in my case) and not symlinks, since I do not want to copy the directories in the from-path (remote) that it is referencing to that is needed to ensure that the symlinks work in the to-path. Also can you help me with initiating the transfer from the to-path (local)

Comment: @WanderingMind that's fine. Initiating the transfer? Just run the copy.